# ConfiguredGraphFactory.open() on JanusGraph returned Cassandra DriverTimeoutException

Tags: cassandra, gremlin, janusgraph

I am new to Janusgraph. We have janusgraph setup with cassandra as backend.
We are using ConfiguredGraphFactory to dynamically create graphs at runtime. But when trying to open the created graph using ConfiguredGraphFactory.open("graphName") getting the below error

```
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: Query timed out after PT2S
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException.copy(DriverTimeoutException.java:34)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.concurrent.CompletableFutures.getUninterruptibly(CompletableFutures.java:149)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestSyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestSyncProcessor.java:53)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestSyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestSyncProcessor.java:30)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:230)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.SyncCqlSession.execute(SyncCqlSession.java:54)
```

***We are using single cassandra node and not a cluster. If we are not using ConfiguredGraphFactory we are able to connect to cassandra & it is not a network/wrong port issue.***

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would start by checking that the correct ports and other networking is in place. That looks to me as if JanusGraph tried to communicate, via CQL, with the backend Cassandra cluster and was unable to and hence timed out trying.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence Here network is not an issue as i am able to successfully run other commands such as ConfiguredGraphFactory.createConfiguration(map) & ConfiguredGraphFactory.getGraphNames() which connects to the single cluster cassandra backend to create/get the details. I am getting the above issue only when i try to open the graph

Answer (score 1):

JanusGraph uses the Java driver to connect to Cassandra. This error comes from the driver and indicates that the nodes didn't respond:

```
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: Query timed out after PT2S
```

The `DriverTimeoutException` is different from a read or write timeout. It gets thrown when a request from the driver timed out because it didn't get a response from the Cassandra nodes after 2 seconds (`PT2S`).

You'll need to check if there's a network route between the JanusGraph server and the Cassandra nodes. One thing to check for is that a firewall is not blocking access to the CQL client port on the C* nodes (default is `9042`). Cheers!

Comment: Here network is not an issue as i am able to successfully run other commands such as ConfiguredGraphFactory.createConfiguration(map) & ConfiguredGraphFactory.getGraphNames() which connects to the single cluster cassandra backend to create/get the details. I am getting the above issue only when i try to open the graph.